# Expression expected?

Tags: sql, .net, visual-studio

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Datetxt.TextChanged

        Datetxt = SELECT date FROM river-derwent-keswick-portinscale WHERE input = date

End Sub
```

Can someone help me fix the expected expression, visual studio says that is at the start of the Select statement.
The variable of input is set on an earlier page and is a global variable and date is a column name in the database.

Comment: Assuming sql-server; try: `[river-derwent-keswick-portinscale]` and `[date]`

Comment: Is it not possible to write something like that directly are u using sqlCommand , sqlDataAdapters and all and if it is a date field and Datetext is a string then u need to use convert to varchar